# Vuejs2 and draw2d js library

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, draw2d-js

**Hello There big community!!!**

Is there any way to use draw2d touch canvas library in a vuejs2 project with webpack template? If yes, could you provide an implementation example?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and help!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually i realized that the problem was not with vue js and draw2d library. It was with webpack and manual import of draw2d library. So the solution is here:
https://libraries.io/npm/draw2d-wrapper.

npm install draw2d-wrapper@1.1.2
or
npm install -g draw2d-wrapper

and then for webpack simply require the library:

require('draw2d-wrapper');

Hope you enjoy then!